# How to set domain of an independent variable in Plot3D?

Tags: plotting

Suppose I want to plot this function $f(x,y)=x^2-y^2$ and I want to set the domain for $y$ to be $1-y$.

I tried in *Mathemtica*,

```
Plot3D[x^2 - y^2, {x, 0, 1}, {1 - y, 0, 1}]
```

But it gives,

> Plot3D::write: Tag Plus in 1-y is Protected.

Any idea, how to handle such situation?

Comment: you can substitute `z=1-y` which is in range `[0,1]` with `y=1-z` therefore the corresponding domain for `y` is `[1,0]`

Comment: `Plot3D[x^2 - (1-a)^2, {x, 0, 1}, {a, 0, 1}]` like this? I renamed plotting parameter to `a = 1- y`to not confus ourselves.  How else to you want this feature to manifest on the plot? (reversed axis etc)